# tabs and pills in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tab structure consisting of 5 tabs. All tabs are working fine. Now in my first tab, I have few header tags which are same as the other 4 tabs. So when clicking of each of them, I want to change the active tab and also the contents. My code is as below.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#overview">Overview</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">tab1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">tab2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">tab3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">tab4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="overview" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <p>overview</p>
    <br>
    <a href="#tab1">
      <h3>tab1 link</h3>
    </a>
    <br>
    <a href="#tab2">
      <h3>tab2 link</h3>
    </a>
    <br>
    <a href="#tab3">
      <h3>tab3 link</h3>
    </a>
    <br>
    <a href="#tab4">
      <h3>tab4 link</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla ut non neque. Vivamus nibh urna, ornare id gravida ut, mollis a magna. Aliquam porttitor condimentum nisi, eu viverra ipsum porta ut. Nam hendrerit bibendum turpis, sed molestie mi fermentum id. Aenean
      volutpat velit sem. Sed consequat ante in rutrum convallis. Nunc facilisis leo at faucibus adipiscing.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <p>WInteger convallis, nulla in sollicitudin placerat, ligula enim auctor lectus, in mollis diam dolor at lorem. Sed bibendum nibh sit amet dictum feugiat. Vivamus arcu sem, cursus a feugiat ut, iaculis at erat. Donec vehicula at ligula vitae venenatis.
      Sed nunc nulla, vehicula non porttitor in, pharetra et dolor. Fusce nec velit velit. Pellentesque consectetur eros.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
    <p>Donec vel placerat quam, ut euismod risus. Sed a mi suscipit, elementum sem a, hendrerit velit. Donec at erat magna. Sed dignissim orci nec eleifend egestas. Donec eget mi consequat massa vestibulum laoreet. Mauris et ultrices nulla, malesuada volutpat
      ante. Fusce ut orci lorem. Donec molestie libero in tempus imperdiet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane fade">
    <p>Donec vel placerat quam, ut euismod risus. Sed a mi suscipit, elementum sem a, hendrerit velit. Donec at erat magna. Sed dignissim orci nec eleifend egestas. Donec eget mi consequat massa vestibulum laoreet. Mauris et ultrices nulla, malesuada volutpat
      ante. Fusce ut orci lorem. Donec molestie libero in tempus imperdiet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help soon will help.

Comment: YoU can structure tabs within tabs just set their I'd to something unique

Comment: that is not what i want. there are some content in the overview page which links to remaining tabs.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused on what exactly you want

Comment: if you can see the code snippet, the first tab has data wherein there are links which on click need to change the tabs accordingly. for Example if i click on tab1 link in the overview tab, it should take me to tab1

Comment: So you wanna click a link and it go to that tab?

Comment: yes thats exactly what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off bootstrap documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

Use a jquery function like this

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#myTab a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').tab('show');
  })
```

THat will work on any a link you click and take you to the tab its href is set to

[Look at this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpBoKY)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to place the content inside `tab-content` to make it work.
This will work like you want it to. Try it:

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab">

<li  class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">tab1</a>
</li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">tab2</a>
</li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">tab3</a>
</li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">tab4</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <p>overview</p>
<br>
<div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
<p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla ut non neque. Vivamus nibh urna, ornare id gravida ut, mollis a magna. Aliquam porttitor condimentum nisi, eu viverra ipsum porta ut. Nam hendrerit bibendum turpis, sed molestie mi fermentum id. Aenean
  volutpat velit sem. Sed consequat ante in rutrum convallis. Nunc facilisis leo at faucibus adipiscing.</p>
</div>
<div id = "tab2" class = "tab-pane fade">
<br>
<p>WInteger convallis, nulla in sollicitudin placerat, ligula enim auctor lectus, in mollis diam dolor at lorem. Sed bibendum nibh sit amet dictum feugiat. Vivamus arcu sem, cursus a feugiat ut, iaculis at erat. Donec vehicula at ligula vitae venenatis.
  Sed nunc nulla, vehicula non porttitor in, pharetra et dolor. Fusce nec velit velit. Pellentesque consectetur eros.</p>
</div>
<br>
<div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
<p>Donec vel placerat quam, ut euismod risus. Sed a mi suscipit, elementum sem a, hendrerit velit. Donec at erat magna. Sed dignissim orci nec eleifend egestas. Donec eget mi consequat massa vestibulum laoreet. Mauris et ultrices nulla, malesuada volutpat
  ante. Fusce ut orci lorem. Donec molestie libero in tempus imperdiet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient.</p>
</div>
<div id="tab4" class="tab-pane fade">
<p>Donec vel placerat quam, ut euismod risus. Sed a mi suscipit, elementum sem a, hendrerit velit. Donec at erat magna. Sed dignissim orci nec eleifend egestas. Donec eget mi consequat massa vestibulum laoreet. Mauris et ultrices nulla, malesuada volutpat
  ante. Fusce ut orci lorem. Donec molestie libero in tempus imperdiet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Run this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXMqXZ)

Comment: this is not what i want. I already got ur code working. What i want is that in my first tab i have a few heading links which link to remaining tabs. for Ex. if i click on tab2 link in overview page, it should take me to tab2.